# python3 inheritance of classmethod

Tags: python, inheritance

In the below code:

1. I created a `Wizard` class, in which I defined the `__init__` method as well as a `@classmethod` `get()` to return an instance of the class.
2. Then I created a `Student` class inherited from `Wizard` class, in which I also defined a `__init__` method and a `@classmethod` `get_student()`. In `get_student`, I called on `super().get()` to return an instance of `Wizard` and initiate the value using `.name` and `.wand`.

But when executing the code, an error shows up, attached below.
May I please ask why?

```py
class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, wand, name):
        self.wand = wand
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        name = input("Wizard name: ")
        wand = input("Wand type: ")
        return cls(wand, name)


class Student(Wizard):
    def __init__(self, name, house, wand):
        super().__init__(wand, name)
        self.house = house

    @classmethod
    def getstudent(cls):    
        wizard_object = super().get()
        name = wizard_object.name
        wand = wizard_object.wand
        house = input("House: ")
        return cls(name, house, wand)


wizard1 = Wizard("black wand", "Albus")
print(f"Wizard {wizard1.name} is using wand type of {wizard1.wand}")

wizard2 = Wizard.get()
print(f"Wizard {wizard2.name} is using wand type of {wizard2.wand}") #Prompt: Tom, silver

student1 = Student("Harry", "Gryffindor", "white wand")
print(f"{student1.name} from {student1.house} is using wand type of {student1.wand}")

student2 = Student.getstudent() #Prompt Tom, silver, Slytherin
print(f"{student2.name} from {student2.house} is using wand type of {student2.wand}")
```

Creating an instance as `student1` works as expected. But creating an instance using classmethod `getstudent()` failed with error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minghaod/python_cs/8/inheritanceMD2.py", line 38, in <module>
    student2 = Student.getstudent()  # Prompt Tom, silver, Slytherin
  File "/home/minghaod/python_cs/8/inheritanceMD2.py", line 20, in getstudent
    wizard_object = super().get()
  File "/home/minghaod/python_cs/8/inheritanceMD2.py", line 10, in get
    return cls(wand, name)
TypeError: Student.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'wand'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. Personally I'm not quite sure what you're asking, because the error message seems clear enough to me, but I have the benefit of experience. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: A temporary workaround would be to use: `wizard_object = Wizard.get()` inside `getstudent()`. However, you need a better solution.

Comment: When you call `student2 = Student.getstudent()`, this eventually executes `return cls(wand, name)` (in `def get(cls):`). Here, `cls` is `Student`, so you're calling `Student(wand, name)`. But you're passing it positional arguments, so what you've actually done is `Student(name=wand, house=name, wand=<MISSING>)`, hence the error.

Comment: What if you don't do the construction in `get`, you just retrieve the necessary arguments? i.e. in `Wizard.get`: `return wand, name`, then `wizard2 = Wizard(Wizard.get())`

Comment: @dROOOze That sounds like an answer to me :) Please post it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `Wizard.get` calls `cls(wand, name)`, the class in `cls` is Student - not Wizard - and so, it wants 3 arguments instead of 2.

The problem here is that despite this *almost* working, this is not typically how one works with an Object Oriented approach. So it is not straightforward to fix either.

I hope you noticed that you are creating an entire `Wizard` just to get its name and wand, just to discard the new object.

Also, the correct thing to do is to have the method in the subclass have the same name - just `get`: when you call `Student.get` you will get a Student, no matter the method is defined in the superclass.

One fix here is to have the `get` methods not call `__init__`: create a raw un-initialized instance, by calling `__new__`, and then set the attributes themselves:

```
class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, wand, name):
        self.wand = wand
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        instance = cls.__new__(cls)
        name = input("Wizard name: ")
        wand = input("Wand type: ")
        instance.name = name
        instance.wand = wand
        return instance


class Student(Wizard):
    def __init__(self, name, house, wand):
        super().__init__(wand, name)
        self.house = house

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):    
        wizard_object = super().get()

        house = input("House: ")
        wizard_object.house = house
        return wizard_object
```

Also, note that by inserting a new argument in the middle of the others in the subclass `__init__` you are helping no one- the expected thing is that the arguments that are common for wizards and students are in the same order, and if you need a new `house` parameter, it should come last.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smarter way to do what you're doing, by doing everything in the constructors.  There's no need for custom creators.

HOWEVER, in my opinion, it is a poor practice to embed I/O like this in a data class.  The I/O should be separate.  What happens when you want to redo your application over the web, or in a GUI?  Now you have to rewrite your data.  Just write a method outside of the class to do the I/O.

```
class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, wand=None, name=None):
        if not wand:
            wand = input("Wand type: ")
        if not name:
            name = input("Wizard name: ")
        self.wand = wand
        self.name = name


class Student(Wizard):
    def __init__(self, name=None, house=None, wand=None):
        super().__init__(wand, name)
        if not house:
            house = input("House: ")
        self.house = house


wizard1 = Wizard("black wand", "Albus")
print(f"Wizard {wizard1.name} is using wand type of {wizard1.wand}")

wizard2 = Wizard()
print(f"Wizard {wizard2.name} is using wand type of {wizard2.wand}") #Prompt: Tom, silver

student1 = Student("Harry", "Gryffindor", "white wand")
print(f"{student1.name} from {student1.house} is using wand type of {student1.wand}")

student2 = Student()
print(f"{student2.name} from {student2.house} is using wand type of {student2.wand}")
```

Those who like cutesy code will note this could be done as:

```
class Wizard:
    def __init__(self, wand=None, name=None):
        self.wand = wand or input("Wand type: ")
        self.name = name or input("Wizard name: ")
```

Comment: `wand or` and `name or` will misbehave if you put an empty string or accidentally some other falsy value. To check for `None`, you should always use `is`, e.g. `self.wand = wand if wand is not None else input("Wand type: ")`